# Объединение множества .tsv файлов в один

Tags: машинное-обучение, dataset

Я делаю ML, чтобы предсказать качество связи в беспроводных ячеистых сетях. У меня есть набор данных, который состоит из огромного количества файлов .tsv (около 4000 штук). Формат файла: topo-2016-01-15-00_00.tsv; topo-2016-01-15-00-00_05.tsv; ...; topo-2016-01-15-15-23_55.tsv. Данные собирались на протяжении 14 дней с интервалом в 5 минут. Содержимое файла показано на рисунке: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я могу объединить данные файлы в один для последующей работы с ними?

Comment: какой суммарный размер файлов и размер свободной памяти на вашем компьютере?

Comment: неправильно нерпавильно и еще раз неправильон

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если позволит память компьютера, то самый простой вариант (Python):

```
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob

files = glob("/folder/dataset/*.tsv")
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, sep="\t", skiprows=1) for f in files], 
               ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Есть ли особенности запуска на colab.research.google.com?
f = это путь до первого файла в папке?

Comment: @gangsta, не знаю, я этим сервисом не пользуюсь. попробуйте... `f` - это переменная цикла, а `list_of_files` - список полных или относительных путей к TSV файлам

Comment: тогда перед переменной df необходимо объявить переменную list_of_files и присвоить ей значение os.listdir('/folder/dataset/*.tsv') ?

Comment: @gangsta, см. обновленный ответ

Comment: Благодарю! Работает!